# (Easy Question) Start X and Unity from Console

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, tty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to boot to console without GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174312/how-can-i-set-my-ubuntu-12-04-lts-to-boot-to-console-without-gui)

A lot of questions without response.
This thread is like this two:

[Start X and Unity from the console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72790/start-x-and-unity-from-the-console)

[How to start X and Unity, without gdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41809/how-to-start-x-and-unity-without-gdm)

I want to start X without lighdm, with Unity or Gnome desktop.

Some says its not possible, others to modify xinitrc.

I want to close this rigmarole:

FIRST OF ALL: in /etc/default/grub change "quiet splash" for "text"

Then `sudo update-grub`

Then reboot -> We get to the login of tty1

---

To start X server I have used startx. It looks for xinitrc of the user logged in and if not, check their configuration file.

That starts X without unity panel nor top bar.

Open terminal and tried `unity --replace`.

Now Unity appears ok but slowed down VERY MUCH.

Other try was running "unity" in tty1 directly. Same result.

Other try -> xinitrc -> exec unity -> Same Result

Other try -> xinitrc -> exec gnome-session session=ubuntu -> Same Result

---

Every time I reach Unity it is slowed down and impossible to handle.
If I start X with lightdm it run smothly.
So lightdm have the answer. It runs some command that we missed.

---

Sum up: I want to start Ubuntu like when loggin with lightdm but loggin from terminal instead.

ANYONE?

Comment: but i think with no solution at all

Comment: disabling lightdm was there.  starting unity by launching lightdm was there.  it answers both your questions

Comment: So I cant use Unity without launching lightdm? I want to login from console instead of from lightdm. Normal start but without lightdm so I can experiment with getty

Comment: you could, but it's not a problem worth solving with the other ones that need solving

Comment: And do you know why I can run Unity and start X but it runs slowly?

Comment: Either use unity or don't.  Don't try and piecemeal it.  it's not worth the trouble, and it comes across as complaining.