# How can I configure `startx` to open the standard desktop environment on 16.04.4?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, startup, gui

On 16.04.4, I changed grub to boot into CLI instead of GUI by changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”quiet_splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”`. I also ran a `multi-user.target` systemctl command (like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/858729/182241)), but I am not appending this setting to the kernel as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1106178/285199).

Now if I run `startx`, I get a blank desktop background with the `X` cursor (as another user shared in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168736/how-to-start-gui-from-command-line#comment912080_168762)). The response is to run `sudo systemctl start lightdm`, which will start the default desktop, but this loads as though I had just started the computer in GUI mode (and prompts me for a login). Is it possible to configure startx to run such that it loads the normal desktop GUI as if I'm already logged in, *since I'm already logged in*?

Notes in case it helps:

- I haven't run the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` for the black & white screen printing because it's not a priority to sterilize the startup that much yet.
- The goal is to run a desktop OS on a 'mostly headless' system, but keep the option to run `startx` in the event a user is seated in front of it. [Yes, I could just have the user run the long 'lightdm' command, but `startx` is just so nice and convenient, not to mention legacy-friendly, and so it would be a great opportunity to educate users about `startx` and help them as we transition into a more linux-populated environment.]

Answer (score 0):

At least on my 16.04 VM, I was able to start a unity session manually using

```
startx /usr/bin/unity
```

It's not entirely satisfactory since without the display manager, it doesn't appear to provide any logout button - you can exit the session by `pkill unity` but bear in mind it won't do any cleanup such as waiting for applications to close gracefully.

The process hierarchy seems to be

```
$ pstree -sp $(pgrep -n unity)
systemd(1)───login(1222)───bash(19282)───startx(8133)───xinit(8155)───unity(8160)───sh(8180)───compiz(8181)─┬─{dconf worker}(8183)
                                                                                                            ├─{gdbus}(8185)
                                                                                                            └─{gmain}(8182)
```

You can create a minimal `~/.xsession` for the command if you want to be able to type `startx` alone.

See also [How to start X and Unity, without gdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41809/how-to-start-x-and-unity-without-gdm)

Comment: Hmmm, that definitely works, although as you said - without the display manager. How can I add or start a display manager?

Comment: ... also, why did `startx unity` work, but just `unity` didn't? (I've seen `unity` mentioned in other answers, so I tried it - along with `gnome-shell` and `unity-2d-shell` (<< https://askubuntu.com/a/148721/182241)

Comment: @user3.1415927 you can start the default display manager using `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target` - but then you will need to log in again graphically. I don't think there's a mechanism to *both* log in directly to a user-session *and* start a display manager